# Help understanding monotocally decreasing sequence inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need help understanding this statement. How is that clear? Is  $\; \underset{\;x>x_o}\inf f(x) = f(x_o)\;$ in this case?

[image: statement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a special case of
$$A \subseteq B \implies \inf A \ge \inf B.$$
Here, $A$ and $B$ are $\{f(x) : x=x_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{f(x) : x > x_0\}$, and the inclusion $A \subseteq B$ holds because $x_n > x_0$ for all $n$.

Your guess about $\inf_{x > x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$ is incorrect: you can make a counterexample where $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $x_0$.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.